# when I write Orm Query to get all project.project data to pass it to webKit report

Tags: odoo

when I write Orm Query to get all project.project data to pass it to webKit report  I get this error :

TypeError: browse_record(project.project, 1) is not JSON serializable

and this my code:

```
def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    # assert len(ids) == 1
    project_obj=self.pool.get("project.project")
    project_ids=project_obj.search(cr,uid,[('analytic_account_id','!=',-1)])
    data = project_obj.browse(cr, uid, project_ids)

    return {'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'report_name': 'taskmng.report',
            'datas': data}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you must pass three things: list of ids, object name, dictionary which contains data.

In your case try this:

```
datas = {
    'ids': project_ids,
    'model': 'project.project',
    'form': {}
}
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
    'report_name': 'taskmng.report',
    'datas': datas
}
```